# time functions in c++

Tags: c++, timer

I need to calculate the number of seconds passed since the beginning of the year.
I'm a little confused with all the time functions I found.

I thought of maybe using timer (finding seconds from 1/1/1970) but how can I continue with this one?

Comment: Show us some code. What problems did you face?

Comment: I don't need you to write a code for me.. just some guidance.. like does using "timer" is really the best way?
Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ by default only has access to the arguably ugly `<ctime>` library, still you can get away with it:

1. Call `time` to obtain the current time as `time_t` (=almost universally, the number of seconds elapsed since 1/1/1970, i.e. the UNIX epoch);
2. convert given time to a `struct tm` (a structure with the various time component - year, month, ... - split) using `localtime`;
3. change this `struct tm` to make it go to the beginning of the current year;
4. call `mktime` to convert back the given `struct tm` to a `time_t`; now you have the `time_t` of the beginning of the current year.
5. subtract this value from the `time_t` you obtained at point 1 with `difftime`; now you have the seconds elapsed since the beginning of the year.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you mean the `time` function. Yes, you can use that. More specifically, take a look at the following:

- `time` (returns current time)
- `localtime` (decodes current time into a form that makes years, months, etc., more readily available)
- `struct tm` (what `localtime` returns)
- `mktime` (converts back from a `struct tm` to a `time_t`)
- `difftime` (computes difference between two `time_t`s in seconds).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <ctime>

double seconds_since_year_began()
{
    time_t now = std::time(NULL);
    tm* tmp = std::localtime(&now);
    tm t = {0};
    t.tm_year = tmp->tm_year;
    return std::difftime(now, std::mktime(&t));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <ctime>
```

and have a look at the example here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/mktime/

You want to use that to get the "seconds since the epoch" for 0:00 Jan 1st and subtract from the value returned by `time()`.